# Identifying Big O Notation of Small Function

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

My professor said the time complexity of this function is `O(sqrt(n))`. However, **I do not understand how he got that answer** or how that logic is `sqrt(n)`, maybe I am bad at math.

How can I identify the time complexity of functions like these?

```
    int foo(int n) {
      int k = 0, sum = 0;
      while (2*sum-k < n) {
         k++;
         sum += k;
       }
      return k;
    }
```

Answer: In the k’th iteration `sum=1+2+3+...+k = k*(k+1)/2`
The while loop continues until `2*sum-k = k^2` becomes more than n.
Therefore, the number of iterations is equal to sqrt(n).
In each iteration the running time is O(1).
Therefore, the total running time is O(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 4):

You already have the answer on your own question. However, if you run the code with `N = 100`, you notice that:

```
 I=1 k=0 (2*sum-k)=0
 I=2 k=1 (2*sum-k)=1
 I=3 k=2 (2*sum-k)=4
 I=4 k=3 (2*sum-k)=9
 I=5 k=4 (2*sum-k)=16
 I=6 k=5 (2*sum-k)=25
 I=7 k=6 (2*sum-k)=36
 I=8 k=7 (2*sum-k)=49
 I=9 k=8 (2*sum-k)=64
 I=10 k=9 (2*sum-k)=81
```

you can clearly see that `2*sum-k = k^2`, and if you look at `N` and the number of iterations `I`, you can see that for `N=100`, that `I=10` so `I=sqrt(N)`. You can test with other `N` sizes, but you will notice the same pattern.

The variable `sum`, will contain the *sum* of the first `K` [natural numbers](https://www.math-only-math.com/sum-of-first-n-natural-numbers.html) therefore

```
sum=1+2+3+...+k = k*(k+1)/2
```

Hence, 2 * sum - k =>  2 * (k*(k+1)/2) - k => k * (k + 1) - k => k^2 + k -  k => k^2. So, from `2 * sum-k < n`, we can now have `k^2 < n`. Hence, k = `sqrt(n)`, since `k` is basically counting the number of iterations,

> Therefore, the number of iterations is equal to sqrt(n).

Now looking into the while body, there is only the statements  `k++;` and  `sum += k;`, which is basically `2x` constant computation, consequently

> In each iteration the running time is O(1).

and finally :

> Therefore, the total running time is O(sqrt(n)).